# Possible to customise ZXing in Android to handle save multiple QR code without reloading of camera?

Tags: android, android-intent, qr-code, zxing

I have successfully integrated ZXing QR Scanner.  What I am doing is to repeat the scan once the user has finished scanning 1 QR code. The problem I faced is that ZXing is extremely slow in reloading of camera if I do multiple scanning of QR codes through this method. Are there better ways? I am looking at saving all the scans without the camera reloading (turning off and on).

I am only scanning my own customised QR codes so I do not need to handle other formats.

Scanning

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
 intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Retrieving

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        // Handle successful scan
        //..
        //Repeat scan for next QR code
        Intent i = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        i.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }
    else  {
        // Handle cancel
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ZXing is not slow at reloading anything -- this is time taken by the camera driver to init the camera. There's not much way around that. But, you can simply not close the camera and keep the preview running if you want.

See the app's bulk scan mode -- it already can scan without stopping to show the results.

Comment: @SeanOwen Could you tell us a way to make use of the results of bulk scan mode from other app?